# Reading Photoshop PSD Files with Layers

Tags: software-recommendation, graphics, photoshop

(There are a few existing questions on Photoshop alternatives, but none seem to focus on reading PSD files specifically)

Say I'm a programmer working with a web designer and would like to implement a design she's produced as a PSD file using Photoshop. It's a fairly complicated design using overlays/animating layers, so the ability to examine the PSD file and turn individual layers on and off is necessary.

Is there an app available in Ubuntu that can read PSD files created by Photoshop?

Alternatively, is there a more linux-friendly file format that Photoshop can export to and still preserve layers?

Comment: Also see the answers to the question at https://askubuntu.com/q/56042

Answer (score 9):

I use [GIMP](http://gimp.org) to open PSD files.

Some more advanced layer groups might be broken, but in most cases it works OK.

Comment: +1 I do the same. On file format: XCF is the GIMP file format. (Open PSD and save as XCF).