# Fast PSD files preview

Tags: software-recommendation

I am looking for PSD files viewer. Gimp is too fat for this job. I need something fast and light.

Answer (score 8):

You may like [Kuickshow](http://kuickshow.sourceforge.net/).

"KuickShow is an image browser/viewer with a nice filebrowser to select images to be shown, slideshow support and the ability to display the following image formats: jpg, gif, tiff, png, bmp, psd, xpm, xbm, pbm and eim. Images can be displayed either in their own window, as large as the image, or fullscreen (which shrinks images too large to display). KuickShow also has a slideshow mode."

[image]

Comment: How to install it in Ubuntu 11.04?

Comment: You will have to download from the site: kuickshow.sourceforge.net/index.html#download

Comment: @desgua does it have a modern succesor? This seems like very outdated (2003) and without simple installer

Comment: @jave.web I'm not aware of a modern successor.

Answer (score 5):

XnViewMP is very good doing the job.

Download it from http://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/

Comment: XnView can't be used in Company setting. It can be used for free only when for personal use, not professional use : have to get License (paid).
i.e. : is provided as Freeware for private non-commercial or educational use (including non-profit organization).
check: http://www.xnview.com/wiki/index.php/License Kuickshow License is GNU General Public License version 2.0 (GPLv2) -- just my 0.25cents

Answer (score 4):

Nomacs is a fast and easy to use program: https://nomacs.org/

**Edit:** From the Nomacs landing-page its a:

> ... free, open source image viewer, which supports multiple platforms. You can use it for viewing all common image formats including RAW and psd images.

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens It's a software for viewing PSD files really fast. Unlike Gimp, this doesn't need heavy module loading during start-up and its interface is quite pleasable to look at.

Answer (score 1):

For simply previewing PSDs I use ImageMagick - fast and displays them properly. Also it's free and available via apt.

Comment: I am not sure what did you meant specificaly, however what I do is to use ImageMagick (sudo apt install imagemagick) commands to generate thumbnails, to get combined layer, you need to address it by [0] so `convert *.psd[0] *.png
` will convert all PSDs to PNG previews (`convert` command is from imagemagick package)

Answer (score 0):

Besides Photoshop, I believe [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) is your best option. Might be the closest to Photoshop.

Comment: Not at all, since GIMP is trying to convert PSD to its own system, therefore data/layer loss/missinterpretation is pretty frequent. It is good for determinating what is aproximately in the PSD or for really simple and standard PSDs.